# Read a text file with variable number of columns to a list

Tags: list, file, r

I have a file like this:

```
mylist.txt
234984  10354  41175 932711 426928
1693237   13462
```

Each line of this file has different number of elements, minimum of 1 element per line.
I would like to read it into a list like this:

```
> print(head(mylist,2))
[[1]]
[1] 234984  10354  41175 932711 426928

[[2]]
[1] 1693237   13462
```

Comment: Since your example list items show spaces preserved between the numbers, it's not clear if you want each line to be a long string, or a vector of numbers.

Comment: Vector of numbers. I'm not sure why it show spaces. Anyways, the aL3xa answer seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming that space is delimiter:

```
fc <- file("mylist.txt")
mylist <- strsplit(readLines(fc), " ")
close(fc)
```

**EDIT:**

If the values are delimited by several spaces (an/or in unconsistent way), you can match delimiter with regular expression:

```
mylist.txt
234984   10354   41175 932711      426928
1693237               13462

fc <- file("mylist.txt")
mylist <- strsplit(readLines(fc), " +")
close(fc)
```

**EDIT #2**

And since `strsplit` returns strings, you need to convert your data to numeric (that's an easy one):

```
mylist <- lapply(mylist, as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer is to first read a list filled with NAs and then removing them like this:

```
l<-as.list( as.data.frame( t(read.table("mylist.txt",fill=TRUE,col.names=1:max(count.fields("mylist.txt"))))) )
l<-lapply(l, function(x) x[!is.na(x)] )
```

I wonder if there is a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the second line by using `lapply` instead of `sapply`

```
    lapply(l, function(x)x[!is.na(x)])
```

Comment: 1. You need it, otherwise read.table takes as a number of columns to read the maximum number of columns in first 5 lines of the file

Comment: @pms Ahh, my test file had the maximum number of columns in the first line. I've updated my answer.